# Forçar autoplay em vídeo(não mudo)

Tags: javascript, html5-video

Estou tentando forçar um autoplay em vídeos com javascript, mas com vídeos não mudo, com vídeo mudo é bem simples, mas com ele com volume funciona 50%, por exemplo, se eu acessar a página do vídeo clicando por uma outra página o autoplay é executado, pois houve interferência do usuário, mas caso já esteja na página do vídeo e dê um F5 o navegador lê como algo programado, sem interferência do usuário e da erro.

Sei que isto é possível pois no Youtube mesmo você dando F5 o vídeo com audio é reproduzido automáticamente, provavelmente há algum evento que seja permitido isto, o que estou utilizando atualmente é resumidamente o seguinte:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(e){
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('video').play();
  },1000);
});
```

E o erro que da quando se tenta dar o autoplay com vídeo com audio por F5 é o de promessa:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

Comment: já tentou usar o event document.ready?

Comment: Inicialmente utilizava jQuery, mas depois passei todo o escopo de script de vídeos para JS puro, mas com jQuery era o mesmo resultado do DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: Bom, não sei como ajudar então, mas é realmente uma boa ideia iniciar a página com som? Porque se o tal vídeo não for o propósito principal da página normalmente é desagradável abrir uma página e começar a sair audio sem que você espere, principalmente se estiver num ambiente público ou de trabalho (gemidão do zap que o diga)

Comment: A aplicação que estou fazendo é de um publico em especifico, não vai ter nada de vídeos aleatórios como o Youtube, foi só o exemplo mesmo, mas na verdade já funciona o autoplay mas só com cliques e mousemove, queria ver se atualizando a página ou de algum outro modo tambem dê.. tipo deixar redondinho o autoplay

Comment: Alguns browsers bloqueiam e só permitem se o usuário clicar mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Siga [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60290908/788190) no stackoverflow geral. Você tem que utilizar o evento onloadeddata, pois pode acontecer de você dar play sem antes carregar o vídeo.

```
<video onloadeddata="this.play();this.muted=false;" poster="https://durian.blender.org/wp-content/themes/durian/images/void.png" playsinline loop muted controls>
    <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag or the file format of this video.
</video>
```

Comment: Você tentou esta parte `this.muted=false;` ?

Comment: Tentando deste jeito ai, o vídeo é pausado no momento do this.muted=false; e da essa mensagem: Unmuting failed and the element was paused instead because the user didn't interact with the document before.